# Create date in format YYYY-MM and add 0 in case month < 10

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a date in the format `YYYY-MM` using `postgresSQL`. 
The month should **always** be **two digits**. 
For example if it is **August 2020** the result should be **2020-08** and not 2020-8.

---

Therefore, I tried to add the `0` in front of the `8` using a `CASE` statement looking like this:

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9cf6d29a332033e245a70ef8bc24e1fa)**

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN DATE_PART('month', date '2020-08-01 00:00:00') <10 
THEN CONCAT('0',DATE_PART('month', date '2020-08-01 00:00:00'))
ELSE 1 END) AS year_month_value
```

---

However, with this query I get error:

```
ERROR:  CASE types integer and text cannot be matched
LINE 3: THEN CONCAT('0',DATE_PART('month', date '2020-08-01 00:00:00...
```

I have no clue how I need to modify the query to make it work. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: The expression after `THEN` should have the same type as the expression following the `ELSE`. In your case `CONCAT...` returns a string, and `1` returns an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-formatting.html):

**General**

```
select to_char(dateval, 'YYYY-MM')
```

**Example [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4ca60a33c4a5246567a5eff2455bbbcc)**

```
SELECT to_char(date '2020-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: I get error column "dateval" does not exist: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=45a4b0b6d9a06e09a685901b7ac6bee6

Comment: The intention was (probably) to do: `select to_char(date '2020-08-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM');`

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I edited the answer accordingly.